# What format config.tvc or how to get it?

Tags: solidity, everscale

```bash
tvm_linker test --help | grep config
        --config <CONFIG> Imports config parameters from a config contract TVC
```

What format or how to get it?

I tried like this:

```bash
tvmos -c em.json config --is_json true \
 --url mainnet.evercloud.dev \
 --access_key <access_key> \
 --project_id <project_id>
tvmos -c em.json dump config config.tvc
```

but when using `config.tvc` I get an error: **exit code 68** — *There is no config parameter 20 or 21*

Expecting: **exit code 0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
tvmos -c em.json account \
-1:5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555 \
--dumptvc config.tvc
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.